# Java I/O - increment name of new target files

Tags: java, url, io

This code downloads 4 links with photos.
Is there a way to create new .png files with a new name ?
For exeample: image1.png , image2.png, image3.png automatically

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class AfbeeldingDown {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.autoguide.com/auto-news/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/mazda-2013-tokyo-auto-salon.jpg");
        URL url1 = new URL("http://www.autoguide.com/auto-news/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/mazda-2013-tokyo-auto-salon.jpg");
        URL url2 = new URL("http://www.autoguide.com/auto-news/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/mazda-2013-tokyo-auto-salon.jpg");
        URL url3 = new URL("http://www.autoguide.com/auto-news/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/mazda-2013-tokyo-auto-salon.jpg");
        InputStream in = url.openStream();

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("image.png");

        int r;

        while ((r = in.read())!= -1) {
            out.write(r);
        }

        in.close();
        out.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: same url is given for all?

Comment: No not same Url. This is just a exemple code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
ArrayList<URL> urlList = new ArrayList();
urlList.add(new URL("http://www.autoguide.com/auto-news/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/mazda-2013-tokyo-auto-salon.jpg"));
urlList.add(new URL("http://www.autoguide.com/auto-news/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/mazda-2013-tokyo-auto-salon.jpg"));
urlList.add(new URL("http://www.autoguide.com/auto-news/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/mazda-2013-tokyo-auto-salon.jpg"));
urlList.add(new URL("http://www.autoguide.com/auto-news/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/mazda-2013-tokyo-auto-salon.jpg"));
int i = 1;
for (URL url : urlList) {
  InputStream in = url.openStream();

  OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("image" + i + ".png");
  i++;
  int r;
  while ((r = in.read()) != -1) {
   out.write(r);
   }
   in.close();
   out.close();
 }
```

and more simple

```
ArrayList<String> imageNames = new ArrayList();
imageNames.add("mazda-2013-tokyo-auto-salon.jpg");
imageNames.add("mazda-2013-Volkswagen-CrossBlue-main.jpg");
for ( String imageName : imageNames) {
    URL url = new URL("http://www.autoguide.com/auto-news/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/"+imageName);
    InputStream in = url.openStream();
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(imageName);
    int r;
    while ((r = in.read()) != -1) {
        out.write(r);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update the code such that it takes as argument the file name you want it to create something like:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //same code as before
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(arg[0]);

        int r;

        while ((r = in.read())!= -1) {
            out.write(r);
        }

        in.close();
        out.close();
}
```

After that you can do all sorts of refinements:

- validate the inputed name, to see if it's not empty (in which case use a default file name) and if it's a valid file name as supported by the current Operating System.
- only pass a file name template as argument (such as "image") and make it add an increment at the end of it such that it creates a new file each time (eg: if "image1.png" exists, the new file name will be "image2.png"). You need to first list all the files starting with "[template]"  in the current directory

Answer (score 0):

With a simple class, this is possible:

```
// Lacks checking, not thread safe etc -- left as an exercise
public final class CountingFileGenerator
{
    private final String prefix, suffix;
    private int count = 1;

    public CountingFileGenerator(final String prefix, final String suffix)
    {
        this.prefix = prefix;
        this.suffix = suffix;
    }

    public OutputStream newFile()
        throws IOException
    {
        final String name = String.format("%s%d%s", prefix, count, suffix);
        final OutputStream ret = new FileOutputStream(name);
        count++;
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
final CountingFileGenerator generator = new CountingFileGenerator("image", ".png");

final OutputStream o1 = generator.newFile();
final OutputStream o2 = generator.newFile();
```

etc etc.

Of course, don't forget to close the returned streams.